# Titlespacing command not working for \subsection and also causing error for \section

Tags: errors, amsmath, titlesec, amsart, documentation

I'm using the packages

```
\documentclass{amsart} 
\usepackage{amsmath}
```

they do not leave a vertical space between the section's title and the following text.

So i'm trying to use the titlespacing command of the titlesec package.

[Here, it says](https://www.overleaf.com/learn/latex/Sections_and_chapters#titlesec_commands)

```
 \titlespacing{<command>}{<left>}{<before-sep>}{<after-sep>}
where:

<left> increases the left margin.
<before-sep> is the vertical space before the title.
<after-sep> is the separation between title and non-sectioning text.
```

so I try

```
\usepackage{titlesec}
\titlespacing{\subsection}{0em}{0em}{0.5em}
```

but I get the error

```
Undefined control sequence.
<argument> ...on\endcsname \protect \@secnumpunct
```

at the lines

```
\section{main}
```

and

```
\subsection{subsection title}
```

I do not understand what is the error, and why it triggers at `\section`, when I only intended to modify `\subsection`

Also, where is the documentation. I spent half an hour searching it, and got nothing.

Here is the complete code

```
\documentclass{amsart} 
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{titlesec} % <- This lines try to modify the subsection
\titlespacing{\subsection}{0em}{0em}{0.5em} % <- This lines try to modify the subsection


\begin{document}

\section{Main section}% <- This line triggers the error
text main section is on new line

\subsection{subsection title} % <- This line triggers the error
I want this text separated on a new line

\end{document}
```

Comment: You should provide a minimal working example that compiles all by itself.

Comment: @User23456234  I added the code

Answer (score 8):

You get

```
! Undefined control sequence.
<argument> ...on\endcsname \protect \@secnumpunct

l.9 \section{Main section}
                          % <- This line triggers the error
?
! Undefined control sequence.
<argument> ...on\endcsname \protect \@secnumpunct

l.12 \subsection{subsection title}
                                   % <- This line triggers the error
?
```

which means just one thing: `titlesec` is not compatible with `amsart`.

Why? Because `amsart` redefines `\@startsection` whereas `titlesec` expects the kernel version of the command. And because at AMS they don't want users to tinker with the style.

```
\documentclass{amsart} 
\usepackage{amsmath}

\makeatletter
% here the original definition
%\def\subsection{\@startsection{subsection}{2}%
%  \z@{.5\linespacing\@plus.7\linespacing}{-.5em}%
%  {\normalfont\bfseries}}
\def\subsection{\@startsection{subsection}{2}%
  \z@{-.5\linespacing\@plus-.7\linespacing}{1sp}%
  {\normalfont\bfseries}}
\makeatother

\begin{document}

\section{Main section}
The text main section is on a new line

\subsection{Subsection title}
I want this text separated on a new line

\end{document}
```

[image]

If you want the first line after the header to be indented change the relevant code into

```
\def\subsection{\@startsection{subsection}{2}%
  \z@{.5\linespacing\@plus.7\linespacing}{1sp}%
  {\normalfont\bfseries}}
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I "solved" it by adding "phantom" text at the end of the subsection title, followed by a paragraph jump.

```
\subsection{subsection title}\phantom{dummy_text}\par\samepage
```

Edit: after egreg comment, I added `\samepage` at the end of the line, to prevent the title to be separated from the next line on different pages.

Comment: Please delete. This is not a solution: you'll have to worry about having the heading at the bottom of the page and the text on the next one.